# AWS ACM / Route 53 Record Addition Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-acm

- I have done email validation for my ACM certificate.
- The certificates are issued
- The "create record in route 53" does not appear
- Only the "resend email validation button remains"
- I need to add a CNAME record for my certificate
- Not sure how to manually enter the information needed to create a CNAME record

Comment: You'll need to create a new certificate to add another name.  There's no way to add a CNAME to an existing certificate.

Answer (score 0):

When you use AWS ACM to validate domain ownership, there are two methods available: [Domain validation and email validation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/domain-ownership-validation.html). If you select email validation when creating your SSL certificate, you do not need to create a CNAME record like you would for domain validation.

Instead, you will receive an email that contains a link to click within 45 days before it expires. This process requires manual intervention, so it may not be the most efficient option. If your domain zone is hosted within Route53, it is recommended that you re-create the certificate using domain validation as it will automatically renew once set up.

Comment: So how do I add my SSL certificate to my Route53 records in regards to the email validation method. Its already approved and issued.

Comment: You have chosen to use email validation as your method for obtaining an SSL certificate. This involves sending an email to the domain name owner for validation, after which the certificate is issued, as you've already mentioned. Another option is domain validation, which involves adding a DNS record to verify domain ownership. Since you have opted for email validation and the certificate is issued, you can now begin using your SSL certificate. No Route53 entry is required.